# 'ng' as CSS prefix name

Tags: css, angularjs

Trying to write an application, and wanted to match CSS prefixes with the Application name.

Can we use 'ng' as a CSS prefix? Or is this served and strictly to be used for the Angular team?

Comment: We're gonna need way more information. You can prefix CSS with whatever you want. What's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "CSS prefix"? Unless you're a vendor making your own CSS engine, you can't define custom vendor prefixes. Are you talking about prefixes on class names, attribute names, something else?

Comment: I am writing my own CSS for an app. And wanted to prefix all the classes for the app with ng-*; for example... .ng-page-header {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're free to use `ng` as a prefix for your CSS classes, but beware that Angularjs also uses that prefix, so you might have name collisions. That wont break your project, but it might have unforeseen styling artifacts. So you either ought to pick a different prefix or be well aware of the names of the classes used by Angularjs internally, so you can gracefully avoid the name collisions.